# How to configure mapbox-gl-js types with flow?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

So I'm using [`"mapbox-gl": "0.50.0"`](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/) and [`// @flow`](https://flow.org) in a react project.

However, when I run flow, it gets into a lot of type errors.

Do I need to add a rule to `.flowconfig` or how do I configure it?

If I add this to my `.flowconfig`

```
[ignore]
.*/node_modules/@mapbox/.*
.*/node_modules/mapbox-gl/.*
```

Then an error is raised when I try to import mapbox-gl in my actual code

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add mapbox-gl into `[libs]` section like this:

```
[libs]
./node_modules/mapbox-gl/flow-typed
./node_modules/mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.js.flow
```

You may also want to ignore some `mapbox-gl` dependencies:

```
[ignore]
.*/node_modules/jsonlint-lines/.*
.*/node_modules/@mapbox/jsonlint-lines-primitives/.*
```

Just for reference, my `.flowconfig` file looks like this:

```
[ignore]
.*/node_modules/jsonlint-lines/.*
.*/node_modules/@mapbox/jsonlint-lines-primitives/.*

[include]

[libs]
./flow-typed
./node_modules/mapbox-gl/flow-typed
./node_modules/mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.js.flow

[options]
esproposal.class_static_fields=enable
esproposal.class_instance_fields=enable

[lints]
```

It works for me with `mapbox-gl` v0.51.0, and `flow-bin` v0.86.0